# Unable to connect flume with mongodb

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, flume

I am new to Hadoop, I am using [Cloudera Quickstart](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html) and I want to connect [flume](https://flume.apache.org/) with my mongodb. I don't know how to connect flume to mongoDB which has set username and password. I am using source type as `netcat`, channel type as `memory` and sink type as `hdfs`.

my `flume.conf` file

```
# Please paste flume.conf here. Example:
# Sources, channels, and sinks are defined per
# agent name, in this case 'tier1'.
tier1.sources  = source1
tier1.channels = channel1
tier1.sinks    = sink1
# For each source, channel, and sink, set
# standard properties.
tier1.sources.source1.type     = netcat
tier1.sources.source1.bind     = 192.168.x.xxx
tier1.sources.source1.port     = 27017
tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
tier1.channels.channel1.type   = memory
tier1.sinks.sink1.type         = hdfs
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path    = /user/cloudera/flume
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
tier1.sinks.sink1.channel      = channel1

# Other properties are specific to each type of
# source, channel, or sink. In this case, we
# specify the capacity of the memory channel.
tier1.channels.channel1.capac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not understand from you question if you actually want to write to MongoDB or read from MongoDB.

I case you would like to **write** to MongoDB, you already have a [good starting point](https://github.com/leonlee/flume-ng-mongodb-sink) to extend or develop you own [custom sink](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html#sink).

In a case you would like to **read** from MongoDB, you will need to implement a solution from scratch, following the examples mentioned on the [Flume Developer Guide](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html#source) (you can reuse some of the parts of the code from GitHub link provided above).

Comment: I followed this link but my mongodb is protected with username and password. so how can i read my mongodb which is protected with username and password, if you please provide some sample conf file it would help.